# Calculating $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(\pi xy)+\sin(\pi(x^2+y^2))}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I just started learning about multivariable calculus, and the only tool we've been presented with when it comes to calculating limits is using sequences.
I need to determent whether this limit exists or not, and if it does, then I need to calculate it.

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(\pi xy)+\sin(\pi(x^2+y^2))}{x^2+y^2}
$$

I've been playing around with different sequences and I believe this limit exists and is equal to $\pi$, however, I couldn't find a way to show that with general sequences, i.e, to show that for every $(x_n,y_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}(0,0)$ also $f(x_n,y_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\pi$.

Comment: Refer also to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969388/505767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The limmand can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1-\cos(\pi xy)}{\pi^2x^2y^2}\cdot\frac{\pi^2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{\sin (\pi(x^2+y^2))}{x^2+y^2}$$

Consider the two terms separately and remember that squeeze theorem is always your friend.